# Nested apply with multiple parameters

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I would like to use the apply family instead of a for loop.

My for loop is nested and contains several vectors and a list, for which I am unsure how to input as parameters with apply.

```
Codes <- c("A","B","C")
Samples <- c("A","A","B","B","B","C")
Samples_Names <- c("A1","A2","B1","B2","B3","C1")
Samples_folder <- c("Alpha","Alpha","Beta","Beta","Beta","Charlie")
Df <- list(data.frame(T1 = c(1,2,3)), data.frame(T1 = c(1,2,3)), data.frame(T1 = c(1,2,3)))


for (i in 1:length(Codes)){

  for (j in 1:length(Samples)) {

    if(Codes[i] == Samples[j]) {

      write_csv(Df[[i]], path = paste0(Working_Directory,Samples_folder[j],"/",Samples_Names[j],".csv"))

    }
  }
}
```

This will give an output of A1,A2 in Alpha, B1,B2,B3 in Beta, and C1 in charlie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking to just use write_csv, we can use `pwalk` from `purrr` to accomplish this over the three equal size vectors. No need to include the loop on `Codes`, as for each iteration in the apply we can `write_csv` the dataset corresponding to where `Samples` is found in `Codes`.

I shortened `Working_Directory` to `WD`.

```r
library(purrr)

pwalk(list(Samples, Samples_folder, Samples_Names), 
      function(x, y, z) write_csv(Df[[match(x, Codes)]], path = paste0(WD, y, "/", z, ".csv")))
```